# I get data using retrofit with post request give message Internal server error

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am using retrofit library with post request, but i did not found data. Give "Internal server error" message.

API_1   :    http://www.fabgrad.com/dummy_api_1/
type    : POST 
data    : { us_id:23 }

interface -

```
public interface FirstApi {
public static String URl = "http://www.fabgrad.com/";

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("dummy_api_1")
Call<Titles> getData(@Field("us_id") String id);

}
```

Using retrofi in main activity -

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(FirstApi.URl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    FirstApi categoryMenuApi = retrofit.create(FirstApi.class);

    String s="23";
    Call<Titles> categoryMenuCall = categoryMenuApi.getData(s);

    categoryMenuCall.enqueue(new Callback<Titles>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Titles> call, Response<Titles> response) {


            Titles list = response.body();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Titles> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I am new in retrofit So please help

Comment: is it correct "dummy_api_1" function name? Your API is not working.

Comment: Check the api with a RestClient first . is it working or not.

Comment: How are you using base Url ?

Comment: check it with postman or any restclient

Comment: Data showing in postman. Api is correct, post request using so use us_id:23

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add `/` at the end of your endpoint `@POST("dummy_api_1")`

Just like:

```
@POST("dummy_api_1/")
```